# Finding the 4th order Taylor expansion of $g(t)= t^3 + 2t^2 + 2t + 1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Given the function $$g(t) = t^3 + 2t^2 + 2t + 1$$

I would like to find the 4th order expansion of $g(t)$ at $t=t_1$.

So far, I have performed the differentiation of $g$, up to $g'''(t)$ w.r.t. $t$, and they are:
$$
\begin{align*}
g'(t) &= 3t^2 +4t + 2\\
g''(t) &= 6t +4 \\
g'''(t) &= 6 \\
\end{align*}$$
and I know (so far) that the Taylor expansion to 2nd order, $g_2(t)$, is
$$g_2(t)  = g(t_1) + g'(t_1)(t-t_1)$$
Subsequently,  the Taylor expansion to 34d order, $g_3(t)$, is
$$g_3(t)  = g(t_1) + g'(t_1)(t-t_1)+\frac{g''(t_1)}{2!}(t-t_1)^2$$

What do I do from here?

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want the expansion of the inverse function $t(u)$ at $u=u_1$?  Or the value of $u$ about a value of $t$ such that $u(t)=u_1$?

Comment: I'm very sorry for the confusion, the function has been fixed.

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly you can't go forward, or the motivation for your work after computing the derivatives. Do you know the general formula for expressing a Taylor series in terms of derivatives?

Comment: I was only given these information by my question, but do not know how to advance from here. My question requires expansion up to 4th order, and in the form in $t_0$

Comment: $t_0$ is the same as $t_1$, no? Oh, and the denominator under $g''(t_0)$ should be $2!$, not $3!$.

Comment: yep, $t_0$ is the same as $t_1$. changed the denominator too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to get the Taylor expansion of a polynomial you would get the polynomial itself at the end. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19x213y_uk4